# how would I add a half transparent background to my navigation bar while having a blue background on my whole page

Tags: html, css

So i have this background for my website. and a navigation bar that has my name and some more stuff. I want to make the background of this navigation bar to be semi transparent so i can see behind. i was using opacity: 0.5; but that makes it white-ish which I do not want. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: probably the body's (or whatever is behind the navigation bar) background color is white

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please add example "code" to help people better understand your question

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this can be achieved - a common solution would be to use a semi transparent PNG file to produce the required effect.

If however you cannot use a PNG (ie, you need to use a JPG) for the navigation bar's background, another approach would be to define a  [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) on the navigation bar.

You can use `relative` and `absolute` positioning as shown below to place this pseudo element inside and behind the navigation element, and apply an apply styling with `opacity` to the pseduo element to achieve the transparent effect:

```css
body {
  background:blue;
}

nav a {
  color:red;
  background:white;
}

nav {
  padding:1rem;
  box-sizing:content;

  /* Required for correct pseudo element placement */
  position:relative;
}

/* Define pseduo element for nav element */
nav::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;

  top:0;
  left:0;
  
  /* Stretch to fill nav */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
  /* Place behind nav content */
  z-index:-1;
  
  /* Set transparency */
  opacity:0.5;
  
  /* The background image */
  background:url(https://i.imgur.com/BZ6HTf5.jpg);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Menu item</a>
  <a href="#">Menu item</a>
  <a href="#">Menu item</a>
</nav>
```